# integrate forum to my site while keeping my design

Tags: php, forum

I have a website which i created from scratch. I want to now add a forum to this but with the users using their excising username and password from when they registered to my site.

What options do i have of already built forum code, with integrating links and keeping my own design?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[phpBB](http://phpbb.com) have some [plugin](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins) so you can integrate your own authentication.

phpBB also let you code your own template so you can keep the forum design consistent with your website.

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476975/how-to-integrate-vbulletin-auth-with-my-site) also show the same kind of solution for vbulletin.

Comment: will i have to use their design or can i integrate my own to it

Comment: there is some template so you can easily modify the look and feel to match your website.