# Django / vBulletin single sign on

Tags: django, single-sign-on, django-authentication, vbulletin

What is the easiest way to make a single sign on (SSO) for a Django project and a vBulletin board on the same domain?

I have an existing database of vBulletin users. I have looked into Django's [RemoteUserBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/) and vBulletin's [vBSSO](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=270517) but I haven't found a complete solution.

Comment: Have you thought about writing a custom django auth backend? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doesn't know Django, but when you are up to something like this, search for "bridges".
There is a high chance someone have already done that for you.

These three source of information can also help you get through doing your own bridge:

**Drupal Bridge**
 http://drupalcode.org/project/drupalvb.git/blob/9b5ab7b93043edfc2fe09c083cc9108344e26577:/drupalvb.inc.php

**CakePHP Bridge**
https://github.com/ceeram/static_bakery/blob/master/src/articles/2010/01/Vbulletin-Bridge-For-CakePHP.rst

**Generic Bridge**
http://www.saurdo.com/11/11/utilizing-the-vbulletin-database-in-your-main-site

Basically you need to look into cookies and match the session hash from vBulletin DB to assure user is logged in, and then you can gather all the user information.

Quoting the third link doing a Generig Bridge:

```
/* Check if session exist then return user id*/
function get_session($hash){

    dbconnect();

    $hash = mysql_real_escape_string($hash);


    $ip = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), 0, 4 - 1));
    $newidhash = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $ip);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM session WHERE sessionhash = '".$hash."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);   

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $sessionhash = $row['sessionhash'];
        $idhash = $row['idhash'];
        $userid = $row['userid'];
        $lastactive = $row['lastactivity'];

        return ($idhash == $newidhash && (time() - $lastactive) < 900) ? $userid : false;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Check cookie values in database:

```
function get_cookie($id, $pass){

    dbconnect();

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ".$id." LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $dbpass = $row['password'];

        // vb might change the salt from time to time. can be found in the /includes/functions.php file
        if(md5($dbpass . '0d582e0835ec6697262764ae6cb467fb') == $pass){
            return $id;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Wrap it all up to determine if user is logged:

```
function check_login(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['bb_userid']) && isset($_COOKIE['bb_password'])){
        if(get_cookie($_COOKIE['bb_userid'], $_COOKIE['bb_password'])){
            return $_COOKIE['bb_userid'];
        }
    }
    if(isset($_COOKIE['bb_sessionhash'])){
        if(get_session($_COOKIE['bb_sessionhash'])){
            return get_session($_COOKIE['bb_sessionhash']);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Retrieve user info to be displayed:

```
function user_info($id){
    dbconnect();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = ".mysql_real_escape_string($id)." LIMIT 1";);
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

And to conclude, use the above functions somewhere. Like this:

```
if($li = check_login()){
    dbconnect();
    $uinfo = user_info($li);

    $q_lastactivity = "UPDATE user SET lastactivity = '".time()."' WHERE userid = ".$li." LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($q_lastactivity);

    if((time() - $uinfo['lastactivity']) > 900){
        $q_lastvisit = "UPDATE user SET lastvisit = '".$uinfo['lastactivity']."' WHERE userid = ".$li." LIMIT 1";
        mysql_query($q_lastvisit);  }
}
```

I hope it might help you doing some progress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I translated the `get_session()`, `get_cookie()` and `check_login()` functions in your third link ([Generic Bridge](http://www.saurdo.com/11/11/utilizing-the-vbulletin-database-in-your-main-site)) directly into Python and it works very well.