# WHMCS - vBulletin v5 Bridge

Tags: vbulletin, whmcs, bridge

Im searching now for some time for a bridge between vBulletin v5 and WHMCS, the bridge should have the option to register an account on both systems, either i create it on vBulletin or WHMCS. Additionally it would be good if there is a shared session, means if i log in into the forum i should be logged on my WHMCS Module, also the way around.

I have looked through some questions and codes and found various scripts but mostly for vBulletin 3.7.
I found also on stackoverflow some scripts between cakePHP and Django to vBulletin:
[Django / vBulletin single sign on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370005/django-vbulletin-single-sign-on/12810874#12810874)

Is there anything known?

Answer (score 0):

WHMCS has said there were no plans for an official module for vBulletin.  You would need to use hooks in WHMCS to create an account in vB when an account in WHMCS is created

http://docs.whmcs.com/Hooks:ClientAdd

You can use the data in the above hook point to pass information along to your vB database to have an account created.

WHMCS uses the same actionhook for when an administrator or a client edits their information. This means that you could make some simple scripts to bridge the database, but you would have to make a field in WHMCS to have the user assign a username for vBulletin (this may be editable by the user).